# Play framework: JSON Reads for a single-attribute case class

Tags: json, scala, playframework, play-json

I'm trying to create a JSON Reads implicit for a case class that contains a single attribute, but I'm getting an error "Reads[Nothing] doesn't conform to expected type". Here's teh codes:

```
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
import play.api.libs.json.{JsPath, Json, Reads}

case class Feedback(message: String)
object Feedback {
  implicit val reads: Reads[Feedback] = (
      (JsPath \ "message").read[String](maxLength[String](2000))
    )(Feedback.apply _)
}
```

Why isn't this working? If I add extra attributes to the case class and multiple `.read` calls joined with `and` it works...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Json combinators doesn't work for single field case class.

You can do the following:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
import play.api.libs.json.{__, Reads}

case class Feedback(message: String)
object Feedback {
  implicit val reads: Reads[Feedback] = (__ \ "message")
    .read[String](maxLength[String](2000)).map {message => Feedback(message)}
}
```

It's because of a limitation in the current Macro implementation. You can read more about it here: [Pacal is the writer of this API](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!starred/play-framework/hGrveOkbJ6U)